# How to copy file from desktop to unix using ssh terminal command

Tags: unix

I am trying to copy a file called TEST.txt from my desktop to Unix server using SSH client. What command would I use to accomplish this task?

Many thanks!!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106480/how-to-copy-files-from-one-machine-to-another-using-ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use scp, like so:

```
scp /file/to/send username@remote:/where/to/put
```

Take a look here for more help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188285/how-to-copy-a-file-from-a-remote-server-to-a-local-machine

Comment: the file is on my desktop. What would be the path for that? I tried scp /TEST.txt and it says the file is ot found

Comment: it would be scp C:/Users/<yourusername>/Desktop/TEST.txt /path/to/remote

Comment: Also what OS are you using? If windows then use the path above

Comment: it says C: hostname and service name not provided now

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes I am going from a windows desktop to a unix server

Comment: Can you post exactly what you typed?

Comment: C:/Users/yuoped/Desktop/TEST.txt username@remote:/test/test/test

Comment: Did you add the scp in front of that?

Comment: my apologies yes I did.... scp C:/Users/yuoped/Desktop/TEST.txt username@remote:/test/test/test

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running a Windows desktop. You can use the SFTP tool in PuTTy or FileZilla to copy files using your ssh credentials.